# php value display images

Tags: php

How to display images on php input value, e.g.:

- if value = 1 then display 1.png
- if value = 2 then display 2.png
- if value > 10 then display full.png & show a link

Answer (score 1):

that would be done like:

```
if($value == 1)
  /*display 1.png*/
if($value == 2)
  /*display 2.png*/
```

and

```
if($value > 10)
    /*display full.png & show a link*/
```

It would however seem like you would need to read up on the [official tutorial to php](http://php.net/tut)

Comment: oky this works thanks : `      <?php $valuecredits = $account['credits'];
  if ( $valuecredits == "3" ) {
  echo "het is nu 3";
  } 
   ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, it would be as simple as this.

```
if(value>10){
    /*display full.png*/
}
```